# R - plotly - hide colorbar

Tags: r, colorbar, plotly

How can I hide the colorbar in the following plotly example taken from their website?

```
    df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_world_gdp_with_codes.csv')

# light grey boundaries
l <- list(color = toRGB("grey"), width = 0.5)

# specify map projection/options
g <- list(
  showframe = FALSE,
  showcoastlines = FALSE,
  projection = list(type = 'Mercator')
)

plot_ly(df, z = GDP..BILLIONS., text = COUNTRY, locations = CODE, type = 'choropleth',
        color = GDP..BILLIONS., colors = 'Blues', marker = list(line = l),
        colorbar = list(tickprefix = '$', title = 'GDP Billions US$'),
        filename="r-docs/world-choropleth") %>%
  layout(title = '2014 Global GDP<br>Source:<a href="https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2195.html">CIA World Factbook</a>',
         geo = g)
```

The figure reference does not provide an answer: https://plot.ly/r/reference/#colorbar. I can hide the colorbar via editing the graph, but I would like to control this in the R code.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try adding `showscale = FALSE` at the trace level.

https://plot.ly/r/reference/#heatmap-showscale

Comment: This works in Python as well, thanks!  `'showscale': False`

Answer (score 22):

Another option is to use `%>% hide_colorbar()`

Comment: This works, seems showscale=FALSE no longer works. Hooray

Comment: @Benbob It works for me, though not in `layout()` but in `plot_ly()`.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up here searching for it in JavaScript. For JS use `showscale :false` after chart type:-

```
   showscale :false,
   type: 'heatmap',
```