# Hiding the color bar on Plotly for web

Tags: javascript, html, web, plotly

Code:

```
<script>
            var z1 = [[1, 2, 1, 10, 3], [1, 4, 3, 1, 2], [8, 4, 5, 1, 2]];
            var x1 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
            var y1 = [3, 6, 9];

                {% if x1 and y1 and z1 %}
              z1 = {{z1|tojson}};
              x1 = {{x1|tojson}};
              y1 = {{y1|tojson}};
                {% endif %}

        var data_z1 = { z: z1, x: x1, y: y1, type: 'surface', colorscale: 'Lava'/*, colorbar: {showscale: false}*/};
        var layout = {
              plot_bgcolor: "#dddddd",
              paper_bgcolor:"#dddddd",
              scene: { camera: { eye: { x: 1.8, y: 1.8, z: 1.5 } } },
              width: window.innerWidth / 100 * 19.2,
              height: window.innerWidth / 100 * 19.2,
              margin: {
                l: 0,
                r: 0,
                b: 0,
                t: window.innerWidth / 100 * 1.94
              }
            };

            Plotly.newPlot('myFunction', [data_z1], layout);

    </script>
```

I'm working on an online Plotly grapher and would like to hide the color bar from view, tried following what's mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297832/r-plotly-hide-colorbar) but no avail.

Comment: Have you tried `layout.marker.colorbar:false` or `marker.colorbar:false` in your layout array?

Comment: Just tried that, didn't work.

Comment: Okay try `fig.update_layout(coloraxis_showscale=False)`

Comment: There is nothing as 'fig' in my code.

Comment: `Ploty.layout(coloraxis_showscale=False)`

Comment: Umm. still no avail, even if I change 'False' to 'false'....Thanks for trying to help whatsoever :)

Comment: NP sorry I have only used it a few times... Best of luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation has it, all that I should've done is

```js
var data_z1 = { z: z1, x: x1, y: y1, type: 'surface', showscale: false};
```

specifically the `showscale: false`.